# Chat script privacy installation question

Tags: php

I recently purchased an advanced chat script which includes free installation on my server. I don't know how to install it but the company says they provide installation if I provide them with the following information:

1. domain name
2. application engine (.net / php)
3. Media server (FMS, Wowza or RED5)
4. rtmp address
5. ftp access
6. database access
7. SSH root access (for Linux) or Remote Desktop (Windows)
8. a couple of test accounts at your veb-site

I don't feel comfortable giving all that info out to them but I know it's required for them to integrate the script to work with my online forum. Not sure what to do.

Comment: "SSH root access"? That's a humongous red flag - what the ******** does anyone need full and unrestricted access for? This "advanced script" company might not be *quite* what they claim to be.

Comment: `I don't know how to install it` -- it doesn't come with instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Why in the hell would root access (or RDP as admin) be needed?

How 'advanced' is this chat script?

Sounds like a bit overkill on the root/admin access . .

But here comes the hard part for me . . you haven't asked a question for us to answer.

What do you exactly want to know? We can't make decisions for you . .